# Sound trigged event with VBS or WSH

Tags: audio, vbscript, speech, wsh

I'd need to build a script (VBS or WSH) which simply run some commands when a specific sound is "listened".
So, it would compare an audio stream (say "blink.wav" file) to any incoming audio track from the OS (win xp).
Note that this would not be any Speech Recognition script, but an audio driven software.

The following is a (more developed) commercial product of what I basically would like to achieve.

http://www.zonetrigger.com/sound-detection/

Is there any code example available?
Is the SAPI interface any useful for my purpose?
Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 1):

There is open source software for that, but it would not be trivial to integrate it into VBS. You can for example build cool things with Python:

http://willdrevo.com/fingerprinting-and-audio-recognition-with-python.html

Overall algorithm to match is simple - you extract some features from the target audio and incoming audio stream and just compare them every moment of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also found this for the record https://github.com/t4ngo/dragonfly Any clue of getting this job done using windows scripting languages or something like WSR Macros http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13045 but for Win XP?

Comment: I really don't want to build an audio fingerprinting software. I need something really simple, and wasting few cpu resources is my primary purpose. The sound the system would have to recognize is identical to the one to compare with. So no complex algorithms are needed.. Just like a string comparison, but, with an audio stream and a file.